# Having issues comparing two characters

Tags: c++, parsing

I am currently making an integer parser using C++, and am having issues comparing two characters. I noticed that the `atoi()` function will allow for a string that has a `'+'` or `'-'` character, and will sign the int accordingly based on the first character of the string being either `'+'` or `'-'`. I am having an issue however with comparing. The for loop will just check the first element if it is not a digit, and if it is not a digit, it checks if it is a negative or a positive character.

Here is my code:

```
for (i; i < 20 && usrIpt[i] != '\0'; ++i) {

    if (i == 0 && isdigit((unsigned char)usrIpt[0]) == 0) {
        if (usrIpt[0] != '+' || usrIpt[0] != '-') {
            isNumber = false;
            break;
        } 
    }
    else {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)usrIpt[i]) == 0) {
            isNumber = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having, is when `usrIpt[0]` is either `'+'` or `'-'`, the program is not breaking from the `if` conditional `usrIpt[0] != '+' || usrIpt[0] != '-'`.

Comment: Please choose a language, either C or C++.  In C++, most, if not all of that loop you wrote could be replaced with `std::all_of`

Comment: `usrIpt[0] != '+' || usrIpt[0] != '-'` this is always true. Perhaps you meant to use `&&`?

Answer (score 1):

> The for loop will just check the first element if it is not a digit,

First, there is no need to put this check within the `for` loop.  Since it is always the first character to test, this test can be done independent of any loop.  If the test passes, then you start the digit checking loop at either index 1 or index 0 of the string, depending on whether there is or is no sign character.

Second, your test for `+` and `-` is wrong.  It will always evaluate to `true`.

Given all this, here is a rewrite of your code:

```
int loopstart = 0;
if ( !isdigit(usrIpt[0]) )  // not a digit, so see if it is + or -
{
    loopstart = 1;
    if (usrIpt[0] != '-' &&  usrIpt[0] != '+')
    {
       // this is not a number, so exit
    }
}
```

Once the test is done, you will either start the loop at the first character or second character:

```
int len = strlen(usrIpt);
for (int i = loopstart; i < len; ++i )  // loopstart is either 0 or 1
{
   // now check if all digits
}
```